# CSV Repeating a string in every row

Tags: perl, csv

Hey people of stackoverflow.

I've got a var i've got to place in every row when printing it into my CSV file and i've got no clue how to do this.

Example of CSV after transform

```
Name; Job; FunctionNumber; **Group**; Afdeling
ASD;  ASD; 1;              12;        Bewaking;
```

Group has to be repeaten with every row enter when printing into my CSV file.

EDIT: CSV Before transform

```
Name; Job; FunctionNumber;  Afdeling
ASD;  ASD; 1;               Bewaking;
```

It's also probbaly for the best to show the code i use to retrieve the group number from the title of the source csv file.

```
        my $filespec = $TMP_Path;
        my $dirname = dirname $TMP_Path;
        my $filename = basename $TMP_Path;



        my $groep = substr($filename,5,index($filename,'.')-5);

        print $groep."\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $group="something";

while (<>) {
    # Trim end of line character
    chomp;

    # Define variables to hold each CSV field
    my ($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4);

    # Break line up on semicolons
    ($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4) = split(';');

    # Output with group in fourth field
    printf("$f1;$f2;$f3;$group;$f4\n");
}
```

Save as "go", then type:

```
chmod +x go
./go < yourfile
```

Comment: In my real CSV data it's not in the end of the line sorry that' my fault.

Comment: So please show us how your data looks BEFORE we start and AFTER we have transformed it.

Comment: This inserts the value of `$group` as both the column heading and that column's values.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert both a new column heading and a repeating value under that column.  Here's one option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $header, $value ) = ( '**Group**', 12 );

while (<>) {
    my $insert = $. == 1 ? $header : $value;
    my @fields = split /;/;
    splice @fields, 3, 0, $insert;
    print join ';', @fields;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

`$insert` takes the value of `$header` if the first line of `inFile` is being read, else the value of `$value`.  The fields are `split`, the new column value is `splice`d into place, then the new line is `print`ed.

Hope this helps!